# If $X$ is a matrix representation fo a group $G$, then its kernel is the set $N=\{g\in G: X(g)=I\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Now I read Sagan's book, GTM 203, the Symmetric group. Now I have some problems in the exercises of Chapter 1.

If $X$ is a matrix representation fo a finite group $G$, then its kernel is the set $N=\{g\in G: X(g)=I\}$. Define a function $Y$ on the group $G/N$ by $Y(gN)=X(g)$ for $gN\in G/N$.

I have proved that

(a). N is a normal subgroup of G and for the coset representation, $N=\cap_{i}g_{i}Hg_{i}^{-1}$ where the $g_{i}$ are the transversal.

(b). $Y$ is a well-defined faithful representation of $G/N$, $Y$ is irreducible if and only if X is.

Now I have no idea for this question:

(c). If $X$ is the coset representation for a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, what is the corresponding representation $Y$?

This problem has bothered me for many days. I would appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: How did these problems arise? (Are they from a textbook? If so, please [edit] the question to include its title & author.)

Comment: You should also show us how you have tried to solve this problem, and perhapse even how you solved the first two parts of the problem, if you think those will be relevant.

Comment: At first glance it seems that this should be the regular representation of $G/H$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But why?

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is normal then by part (a) the kernel of the coset representation $X$ is just $H$ itself, so $Y$ is indeed a representation of $G/H$.

I am not sure how your book formalizes the coset representation, but one way is taking a free vector space $V$ on the set of cosets $G/H$; that is, we have a basis whose elements are the cosets of $H$ in $G$, and elements in the vector space are just formal sums of these basis elements. For instance, $3(g_1H) + 7 (g_2H)$ could be one vector in this space. Addition is defined componentwise, so $$(3(g_1H) + 7(g_2H)) + (4(g_1H)) = 7(g_1H) + 7(g_2H).$$ Thus the zero vector is $0(g_1H) + \dots + 0(g_nH)$ where the $g_i$ are a transversal.

Then $X$ can be thought of as a homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$, and we can define $X(g)$ by defining how it acts on a basis of $V$. For the coset representation, we want $X(g)(aH) = (ga)H$ for any $g,a\in G$. If you would like to think of this as a matrix representation, then you can just identify $V$ with $\mathbb{C}^{|G:H|}$, with an isomorphism given by mapping $g_iH$ to $e_i$ (the $i$th standard basis vector) for each $g_i$ in a transversal set.

The point is that now $Y$ is a homomorphism $G/H\to GL(V)$ such that $Y(gH) = X(g)$. So In particular $Y(gH)(aH) = (ga)H$ for any $g,a\in G$. This is exactly the left regular representation of $G/H$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just now I solved this problem by using characters: 
Compute the character $\chi$ of Y. When $g\in H$,
$$
\chi(H)=\mathrm{tr}(Y(H))=\mathrm{tr}(X(\epsilon))=|G/H|.
$$ 
And otherwise, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\chi(gH)&=\mathrm{tr}(Y(gH))\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(X(g))\\
&=\text{the number of fixed points of $g$ acting on $G/H$}.
\end{aligned}
$$
But if $gg_{i}H=g_{i}H$ for any $g_{i}$ , we must have $g\in H$, which is not the case; i.e., there are no fixed points if $g\notin H$. 

That is $\chi=\chi^{reg}$